# How to change from jList to JTable (data from DB have many columns and rows)

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

I'll try to explain as good as I possibly can. I'm a noob and have been trying to fix this for hours now...

- I have made a Java application that shows data from a Database that it is connected to. (ODBC/Microsoft SQL).
- When I made the GUI for the application I decided to show the data in a jList.
- I then realized that the information is too much and that I need column names etc (therefore an jTable)

**What I want to do is to CHANGE so that the data shows up in a jTable instead of the jList. But I have no clue how to do it.**

This is what the code looks like for now:

**GUI**

```
private void jComboBox1_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)throws SQLException {

    String selected = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
     String[]tmp = conn.showTable1(selected);
    jList1.setListData(tmp);

}
```

**Controller**

```
public String[] showTable1(String table)throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> list1 = dal.showTable1(table);
    return list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
 }
```

**Data Access Layer**

```
public ArrayList<String> showTable1(String table)throws SQLException {
    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String query1 = "select * from [" +table+"]";
        System.out.println(query1);
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query1);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rset.getMetaData();
    while (rset.next()) {
        String result = "";

        for(int i = 1; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            result += rset.getString(i) + "\t" + "\t";
   //     
        }
            list1.add(result);
        }

    return list1;

    }
```

Please help!

Kind Regards, Chris

Answer (score 2):

See [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for a couple of simple suggestions:

1. Search the web for an existing `ResultSetTableModel`.
2. Use the `TableFromDatabase Example` code
3. Use the ListTableModel presented in the blog

Comment: 1.

 public ResultSetTableModel(ResultSet rs) {
    this(rs, 0);
  }



2. 

ListTableModel model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet( resultSet );
JTable table = new JTable( model );

Comment: I don't get it since I have the combobox. When I select a string in the combobox it automatically shows the data in the jList..

Comment: @Chris, I don't understand your comment. The combo box is just used to build the SQL query. Once you have a ResultSet you can create a TableModel and display the data in a JTable.

Comment: JTable has very similar structure like as table in db, rest is decribed in Oracle tutorial - How to use Tables